# Dictionary<string,dynamic> behaves differently when used in function where built than when used out of function, why?

Tags: c#, dictionary, object, dynamic

Using debug in VS 2019 on Windows Server 2019.  I'm loading a Dictionary<string, dynamic> in a function to be used throughout the program.  When I extract the dynamic object (o) from the Dictionary (dictGen) in the function (LoadStuff), it works fine.  However, when it returns from the function, I can't extract the value from the Dictionary and use it as an dynamic object the way I did in the function.

So, here's a short version of the function:

```
private void LoadStuff(ref Dictionary<string, dynamic> dictGen) 
{
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic o = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>("{}");
o["matchField"] = "i";
o["newField"] = "language";
dictGen.Add("sub div", o);
o = null;
o = dictGen["sub div"];
// in Immediate Window, typing o["matchField"] Displays "i" 
}
```

Then in the calling function, the LoadStuff is called:

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> dictGen = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
void LoadStuff(ref dictGen);

dynamic o = dictGen["sub div"]
// In Immediate window or in use, typing o["matchField"] gives following error:

"error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"
```

I've tried explicitly casting dictGen["sub div"] as dynamic, using foreach loops like:

```
foreach(dynamic obj in dictGen.Values)  // using obj["matchField"]
foreach(var key in dictGen.Keys) // obj = dictGen[key]
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> ooo in dictGen) // dynamic obj = ooo.Value;
```

But same problem no matter which way I try it. So, what's different using the Dictionary in the function from using it when it returns? How do I get the value for obj["matchField"]?

Comment: What type of `serializer` are you using? What type of object is `serializer.Deserialize` actually returning at runtime?

Comment: The code you've provided isn't the code you're running: the `void` in your main method would prevent compilation. I've tried what you're describing using serializers from both Json.NET and YamlDotNet, and I'm not seeing the behavior you describe. Please update your question to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I added JavaScriptSerializer to the original post.  And yes, it's not the whole code.  What's shown is not in the main method and it does compile.

Comment: @Velocedge there is no way to help you when you can't show the error - [MCVE] is needed so someone can reproduce and understand the error to help you. Showing code that compiles/works fine and asking why some *other* code does not work is not really how SO works.

Comment: MRE works properly so not much point in posting that.

Comment: If it doesn't reproduce the issue, then it's not an MRE. I'm as curious as you are to find out why you're seeing the behavior you're seeing. The easiest way to do that would be to take your current example and start removing elements until you can identify the change that switches from reproducing the issue to not reproducing it anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is part of a huge Windows Service but I have some ideas on what to take out.  Since it's working it's a much lower priority but I will post an answer if I find one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I had hoped someone would have given me some ideas that would lead to a good answer but that didn't happen.  So, I created a plain ole C# object and used that in the Dictionary rather than the dynamic.  It worked fine in the real program so I'm going use that even though I would have really like to have found why the dynamic object behaved the way it did.